# Key pairs don't match?

Tags: javascript-sdk

Im building a bot that connects Stellar with Telegram but when I generate a new set of key pairs them don't match when I sign in stellarterm.

Here is the code:

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');

// Stellar

function Wallet(){
  var pair = StellarSdk.Keypair.random();
  return{
    secret: pair.secret(),

    public: pair.publicKey()
  }
}
```

I'm trying to access like this:

```
Wallet().secret 
Wallet().public
```

But it returns me wrong set of pair keys. Any idea why it is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Each time your call the `Wallet` function it generates a new keypair. 
You should save the invocation result into a variable:

```
var keypair = Wallet()
console.log(keypair1.secret, keypair2.public)
var anotherKeypair = Wallet()
```

Comment: Thank you Orbit I see it returns now the correct set of keys but just one time. Do you know a way it can returns different key set each time I call the function?

Comment: My friend, you should really start from learning the fundamentals. You won't be able to create anything adequate without basics. There are a lot of interactive JavaScript tutorials out there: [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/). Also check [modern es6 standard features](https://codeburst.io/es6-tutorial-for-beginners-5f3c4e7960be) and learn the basics of [NodeJS](https://blog.codeship.com/node-js-tutorial/). You will find answers for most of your questions there.